# How to correct use an if/else statement looking for a null value?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, error-handling, null

My current code is as follows (note that `getId()` returns a `string` value):

```
 if(person.getId()==null){

    //do something
else{

    //do something else

}
```

However, I am still getting a `null Pointer exception` if the value for `person.getId()` is null.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do an if not null check, then else.

Comment: That depends on what "do something" does.

Comment: Are you sure person is not null?

Comment: you need to be sure person is not null

Comment: No sometimes the value can be null, and other times it has a value

Comment: they are telling you that  **person** is null, not the id, hence the NPE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the test is something like:

- Object is not null
- property of object is what is needed

For your example you need probably to do something if person exists and has no id.

```
if (person != null && person.getId() == null) {
    // Do something, for example create person on the db
}
```

This solve the problem that `person` is null.

---

Note that probably having `person` `null` here is an error.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if(person == null || person.getId() == null) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: `if(person == null && person.getId() == null)` should be choosen over `if(person == null || person.getId() == null)` since the JVM will stop the check after person == null if it's not null while the || (or) will lead to the second statement also beeing checked.

Answer (score 1):

Take a [read about Optional](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html) that was introduces in Java8

for some classes, like String, you can do "value".equals(myString) instead myString.equals("value"), if myString is null assertion will fail instead throw NPE.